# I have no idea why my css file isn't updating on my local server?

Tags: html, css, localhost

My css file just isn't being updated on my local server but I know that its connected because it still has the background colors i assigned before but even if i change the background colors they stay the same! I have restarted everything and tried everything I don't know whats going on.

Heres my header links

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP Test Stuff</title>
<meta name="description" content="PHP test stuff">
<meta name="author" content="Cosmichero">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
```

Also my html and php updates fine its just this file its like its saved and I can't edit it. I feel like I'm just missing something stupid though.

Comment: cleared your cache in the browser?

Comment: The browsers cache all files, use `CTRL+F5` to reload the page (that will clear cache and reload the page). I'm sure Chrome does that, not 100% sure about Firefox.

Comment: I'll try it its probably that and im probably stupid

Comment: CSS can be a little strange with caching. Sometimes the classic `CTRL + F5` combo doesn't even work. Try holding `SHIFT` while clicking on the refresh icon to ensure that the CSS comes through correctly :)

Comment: It worked...... whyyyyy did i forget that and I've worked in this browser and editor for years and have never encountered this XD thank you good ppl

Comment: If you are using chrome there is a setting in the developer tools that disables the cache. Very useful.